# I want to use a div as a twitter bootstrap modal link

Tags: javascript, twitter, modal-dialog

Can help me? I want to use a div as a twitter bootstrap modal link. when i will click on a div it will call a modal. is it possible? if possible then please show me a way. I think it is possible but i dont know how to do this. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$modal.modal('show');` in your `onclick` event handler.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="my-div"></div>

<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var $modal = $('.modal').modal({
    show: false
});
$('.my-div').on('click', function() {
    $modal.modal('show');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/RSJAv/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/jeF7F/).

Your HTML:

```
<div data-toggle="modal" href="#example">Launch modal</div>

<div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
        <p>You can add some text here.</p>              
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your JS (assumes you are already including the needed bootstrap files, both JS and CSS):

```
$(function () { 
   $("#example").modal({show:false});  
});
```

Comment: So @Taslim, generally when an answer was helpful you vote it up. You also mark whichever one worked best for you as "Accepted". You do this and people will be more likely to answer any future questions you may pose.

Comment: @Taslim - To vote up useful answers click the up arrow above the number 0 at the start of each answer. To mark one specific answer as "accepted" click the checkmark symbol underneath the down arrow below the 0. In general this will encourage users to answer your questions as they know they might get votes from you

Comment: Yep, there is no longer that CSS file at the GitHub.